# Ambiguity in friend_Count in user table [FQL]

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I am working on FQL to retrieve the friends count of a particular user.

When i use the query `Select friend_count from user where uid = me()` I get a number which is different from the count i get from this query i.e `select uid2 from friend where uid1= me()`

Why is an ambiguity here?

Does friend_count also includes pending requests then?

If yes how can retrieve those UIDs?

`Select friend_count from user where uid = me()` returned me X and `select uid2 from friend where uid1= me()` returned me Y.

My X is greater than Y which makes me think if X includes the pendin g requests but i am not able to find (X-Y).

Comment: Perhaps you are hitting a query limit on the second one ?

Comment: @Aviram Nope. The first one returned me 948 and the when i manually counted the list of uids returned by second its 906. So I thought the 42 will include either the subscribers or pending request. Now after investigating further i doubt these are the uids of those who had deactivated their profile because the user table doesnt have a matching name to their UIDs. Am i correct?

Answer (score 1):

The difference is that `friend_count` returns the total number of friends, regardless of their privacy settings.

Counting the results of `SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1= me()` may be lower because users who have either restricted their visibility in *Settings->Apps->Apps Others Use* or have turned off Platform Apps will never be returned in FQL or Graph API queries.